# Proof for intersection of isentropic curves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

The following question is from Heat and Thermodynamics by Zemansky and Dittman: prove that isentropic curves do not intersect for a system of two independent variables, and for a system of more than two independent variables, they do generally intersect.

My attempt: for the first part, I can take any two independent variables, then by the equation of state of the system, entropy is uniquely determined by values of these two coordinates. Thus, intersecting isentropic curves would imply the same value of variables corresponding to two different values of entropy, a contradiction.

I am stuck on the second part, could someone help by giving a hint about it?

Comment: This is not really a "home-work problem" as normally understood unless we also consider as a home-work problem the prof assigning a chapter to read and the pupil does not quite get the *meaning* of the second paragraph and is asking for an explanation. True, these are problems 6.13 and 8.17 in Zemansky-Dittman but I dare say that almost all questions in this forum can be viewed in exactly the same light with or without an explicit  text-book reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your line of thinking is that the purpose of proving that isentropic lines of two variables do not intersect is to prove the *existence* of the entropy function and not the other way around.

Given a thermodynamic system whose extensive variables are $x_1,x_2,..x_N$ so that the reversible work is $\delta W = \sum_k y_k dx_k$ and according to the 1st law $\delta Q = dU-\delta W$.

Ddenote by $\mathcal P_0$ any state the system may occupy. Now examine all the states $\mathcal P$ that can be reached from $\mathcal P^0$ reversibly and adiabatically, that is states such that in the path from $\mathcal P^0$ to $\mathcal P$ at every instant $\delta Q = 0$.

Now the general statement you wish to prove is as follows: there is a function $r=r(\theta, x_1,x_2,...x_N)$, where $\theta$ denotes the empirical temperature, such that if $\mathcal P^0:=\{\theta^0, x_1^0,x_2^0,...x_N^0\}$ then every state that can be reached via a reversible and adiabatic path lies on the same surface $r=r(\theta, x_1,x_2,...x_N) = r^0$ for some $r^0=r(\theta^0, x_1^0,x_2^0,...x_N^0)$ number.

These surfaces $r$ *fill* the configuration space of coordinates $\theta,x_1,x_2,...x_N$ and teh surfaces can be numbered in a monotonically increasing manner.

That this is true is one way of saying that *entropy* exists.

For a two-variable system, that is one for which $\delta W =y_1dx_1$ the surfaces simplify to be 1D curves. The usual justification in that special case is that if a pair of isentropic curves could cross then connecting them anywhere with an isothermal would contradict Kelvin's postulate of impossibility of extracting heat to be converted completely to work in a cycle. Of course, in general, we can have isentropic (adiabatic reversible) curves intersect, just take a cycle on any of the isentropic surfaces for $N\ge 2$. Say, from $\mathcal P^0$ take two isentropic paths, $c_1$ and $c_2$, one to $\mathcal P^1$ and another to $\mathcal P^2$ and let an isothermal connect $\mathcal P^1$ and $\mathcal P^2$. Since it is a cycle $\oint dU=0$ in other words $\oint \delta Q =-\oint \delta W$ but this is not a problem if $\oint \delta W=0$

Comment: "Now the general statement you wish to prove is as follows: ............ number." Could you explain simply what this means and how it connects to isentropic curves not intersecting in an n-dimensional space, n>2? Also, here we are talking only about reversible processes right?

Comment: Claim: there exists a nonintersecting set of surfaces in the configuration space so that you can assign an individual nonrepeating number to every one of these surfaces. A geometric example: concentric spheres $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=a^2$, these spheres of radius $a$ starting form $a=0 \to \infty$ fill up the whole space of $x,y,z$, one sphere for each point. these are space filling nonintersecting surfaces. The isentropic surfaces of the thermodynamics space are similar in topology, there is one surface for each state,

Comment: and two states on the same surface can be connected by an adiabatic reversible path fully lying within the surface. In the case of one nonthermal interaction $\delta W = y_1dx_1$ the surface is just a curve, so two points (states) lying on the same curve can only be connected one way but the whole thermodynamic space of two variables $\theta, x_1$ is filled with these curves without "gaps". Of course, you can equally well represent any state with $\theta, x_1,x_2,..x_n$ just as well as with, say, $y_1$ replacing $\theta$ to be $y_1,x_1,x_2,...,x_N$.